# Long garbage-collection time in AEM

Tags: java, garbage-collection, aem

I am facing issues with my publisher, where it takes long GC time. What could be the reason behind this? How to resolve it?

When I checked the usage score of heap memory allocation via http://<<publisher_server>>:4503/system/console/memoryusage, found that

1. PS Eden space - 75%
2. PS Survivor space - 0% - May be this is saying something
3. PS Old gen - 99%

What could have been wrong happening here? Any pointers!

Comment: This could be a memory leak or a heap with wrong configuration. Please attach heap size Xms and Xmx values and screens taken after analysing a heap dump. You can use Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool to analyze a heap dump

Comment: Eden is for newly allocated objects, Survivor for objects that aren't old enough to move to tenured. You are most certainly running out of tenured space, triggering numerous full gc:s. Try increasing memory and run gc logging.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! As a quickfix - I re-started the server and it's working fine. However, I have taken the heap-dump for further analysis for any memory-leaks..